# The relation between toco, tflite_convert and TFLiteConverted

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am a bit confused by how these 3 relate to each other. As far as I understand `tflite_convert` is just a command-line interface to `TFLiteConverter` class. Is that right?

Also, by reading some docs I get it that `toco` is deprecated and should not be used, whereas `tflite_convert` is the future.

Is that right? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The TensorFlow Lite converter comes with a Python API and a CLI.
The cli can be accessed through tflite_convert, and the Python API is accessed through `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter`

As you mentioned, toco is deprecated in favour of TFLiteConverter.